# Why cant I align the two textfields in one line

Tags: html, css, alignment, textfield

Im not able to align two textfields in a single line using the following css

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; box-sizing:border-box; }
a>img { border: none; }
header, footer, article, section, nav, aside { display: block; }

/* === General === */
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background:#ddd;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
/* === Credit Card === */
.credit-card {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:93.75%;   /* This is 300px on 320px wide screen */
    max-width:500px;    /* Just to make sure that it doesnt get crazy on bg screens */
    min-width:300px;    /* And make sure that it contains at least some size */
    margin:30px auto;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:6px;
    z-index:1;
}

.credit-card .inputs {
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:30px;

}

.credit-card .inputs li {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}


.credit-card .inputs li.last {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire {
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire input{
    float:left;
    width:35%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire input.month{
    width:30%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.cvc-code {
    float:right;
    width:20%;


}
.creditcatd .inputs ul.cvc-code{
    display: inline;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.cvc-code input {
    width:70%;
}

.credit-card .visa-watermark, .credit-card .mastercard-watermark {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    display: none;  
}

.credit-card form {
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}

.credit-card .visa-logo, .credit-card .mastercard-logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    right:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: none;  
}

/* === Visa === */
.visa {
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.visa h2 {
    text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(17,121,173,0.8);
}

.visa .visa-logo {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    font-size:2em;
    font-style:italic;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(17,123,173,0.9);
    display: block;
}

.visa .logo:after {
    content:' ';
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.visa .visa-watermark {
    display: block;
    bottom:-100px;
    left:-50px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.06);
    font-size:20em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
/* === Mastercard === */
.mastercard {
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.mastercard h2 {
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #2D4DAA;
}

.mastercard label {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.mastercard input {
    border:1px solid rgba(39,70,157,0.8);
}

.mastercard .mastercard-logo {
    display: block;
}

.mastercard .mastercard-logo div {
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:rgba(239,209,57,0.8);
}

.mastercard .mastercard-logo div:first-child 
{
    background:rgba(223,40,40,0.8);
    margin-right:-10px;
}

.mastercard .mastercard-watermark {
    display: block;
    bottom:-130px;
    left:15%;
}

.mastercard .mastercard-watermark div {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background:rgba(239,209,57,0.1);
}

.mastercard .mastercard-watermark div:first-child {
    background:rgba(223,40,40,0.1);
    margin-right:-60px;
}
.mastercard .demo
{
        float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background:rgba(239,209,57,0.1);
}
/* === Forms === */
label {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(17,123,173,0.6);
}

input {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 8px;
    color:#999;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px  1px 1px #fff;
    border:1px solid rgba(16,103,133,0.6);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius:3px;
}

input.full {
    width:100%;
}


/* === Gradients === */
.visa.gr-cards {
    background: #1db1cf; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%, #1078ab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1db1cf), color-stop(100%,#1078ab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1db1cf', endColorstr='#1078ab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.mastercard.gr-cards {
    background: #4d86ce; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%, #2d4daa 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4d86ce), color-stop(100%,#2d4daa)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d86ce', endColorstr='#2d4daa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.gr-input {
    background: #d3d3d3; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%, #d9d9d9 38%, #e5e5e5 82%, #e7e7e7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d3d3d3), color-stop(38%,#d9d9d9), color-stop(82%,#e5e5e5), color-stop(100%,#e7e7e7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d3d3d3', endColorstr='#e7e7e7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/* General button style (reset) */
.btn {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.btn:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

/* Pseudo elements for icons */
.btn:before,
.icon-heart:after,
.icon-star:after,
.icon-plus:after,
.icon-file:before {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.icon-envelope:before {
    content: "\e000";
}

.icon-cart:before {
    content: "\e007";
}

.icon-cart-2:before {
    content: "\e008";
}

.icon-heart:before {
    content: "\e009";
}

/* Filled heart */
.icon-heart:after,
.icon-heart-2:before {
    content: "\e00a";
}

.icon-star:before {
    content: "\e00b";
}

/* Filled star */
.icon-star:after,
.icon-star-2:before {
    content: "\e00c";
}

.icon-arrow-right:before {
    content: "\e00d";
}

.icon-arrow-left:before {
    content: "\e003";
}

.icon-truck:before {
    content: "\e00e";
}

.icon-remove:before {
    content: "\e00f";
}

.icon-cog:before {
    content: "\e010";
}

.icon-plus:before,
.icon-plus:after {
    content: "\e011";
}

.icon-minus:before {
    content: "\e012";
}

.bh-icon-smiley:before {
    content: "\e001";
}

.bh-icon-sad:before {
    content: "\e002";
}

.icon-file:before {
    content: "\e004";
}

.icon-remove-2:before {
    content: "\e005";
}

/* Button 1 */
.btn-1 {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Button 1e */
.btn-1e {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-1e:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.btn-1e:hover,
.btn-1e:active {
    color: #0e83cd;
}

.btn-1e:hover:after {
    height: 260%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.btn-1e:active:after {
    height: 400%;
    opacity: 1;
}
/* Button 1c */
.btn-1c:after {
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.btn-1c:hover,
.btn-1c:active {
    color: #1BA7C9;
}

.btn-1c:hover:after,
.btn-1c:active:after {
    width: 100%;
}





.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 28px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: white #f7f7f7 #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.dropdown:before, .dropdown:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 9px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px dashed;
  border-color: #888 transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown:before {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown:after {
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 130%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 10px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #62717a;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  /* Fallback for IE 8 */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  /* "transparent" doesn't work with Opera */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  color: #394349;
  outline: 2px solid #49aff2;
  outline: 2px solid -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.dropdown-select > option {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fix for IE 8 putting the arrows behind the select element. */
.lt-ie9 .dropdown {
  z-index: 1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select {
  z-index: -1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Dirty fix for Firefox adding padding where it shouldn't. */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .dropdown-select {
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
}
.fsSubmitButton
{
float:left;
width:20%;
padding: 7px 12px 8px !important;
font-size: 15px !important;
background-color: #57d6c7;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #57D6C7;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}
.fsSubmitButtonM
{
float:left;
width:20%;
padding: 7px 12px 8px !important;
font-size: 15px !important;
background-color: #3dbdae;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #57D6C7;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}


/* === Card Selection === */
.card-select {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

.card-select h2 {
    font-size:1.5em;
    color:#555;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.card-select .wrap {
    width:300px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #A0A0A0;
    background:rgba(176,176,176,0.4);
    border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.card-select a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.card-select a img {
    width:15%;
}

/* === Cards === */
.cards {list-style:none;}
.cards>li {display:none;}
.cards>li.active {display:block;}
```

My html is

```
<body>
  <section id='cards' class="credit-card visa gr-cards">
        <div class="logo visa-logo">visa</div>
        <div class="logo mastercard-logo"><div></div><div></div></div>
        <form action="./credit.php" method="post">
        <input id="txtEncryptionKey" name="txtEncryptionKey" class="tokenex_encryptionkey"
        type="hidden" value="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvWpIQFjQQCPpaIlJKpeg
        irp5kLkzLB1AxHmnLk73D3TJbAGqr1QmlsWDBtMPMRpdzzUM7ZwX3kzhIuATV4Pe
        7RKp3nZlVmcrT0YCQXBrTwqZNh775z58GP2kZs+gVfNqBampJPzSB/hB62KkByhE
        Cn6grrRjiAVwJyZVEvs/2vrxaEpO+aE16emtX12RgI5JdzdOiNyZEQteU6zRBRJE
        ocPWVxExaOpVVVJ5+UnW0LcalzA+lRGRTrQJ5JguAPiAOzRPTK/lYFFpCAl/F8wt
        oAVG1c8zO2NcQ0Pko+fmeidRFxJ/did2btV+9Mkze3mBphwFmvnxa35LF+Cs/XJH
        DwIDAQAB" />


    <button name="cc" class="btn btn-1 btn-1c">Credit Card</button>
    <button class="btn btn-1 btn-1c">Debit Card</button>
    <button class="btn btn-1 btn-1c">Internet Banking</button>          

            <ul class="inputs">
                <li>
                    <label>Card Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cardnumber" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" class="class=tokenex_data full gr-input" required />
                </li>
          <li>
            <label>Name on card</label>
            <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
                     <label>Card Type</label>

                <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
        <option value="1">Visa</option>
        <option value="2">Mastercard</option>

      </select>
    </div>          
</li>
                <li class="expire last">
                    <label>Expiration</label>

                <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="1">Jan</option>
        <option value="2">Feb</option>
        <option value="3">Mar</option>
     <option value="4">Apr</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">Jun</option>
     <option value="7">Jul</option>
     <option value="8">Aug</option>
     <option value="9">Sep</option>
     <option value="10">Oct</option>
     <option value="11">Nov</option>
     <option value="12">Dec</option>

      </select>
    </div>          

            <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select year gr-input">
        <option value="">Year</option>
           <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
     <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
     <option value="2019">2019</option>
     <option value="2020">2020</option>
     <option value="2021">2021</option>
     <option value="2022">2022</option>
     <option value="2023">2023</option>
     <option value="2024">2024</option>
      </select>
    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="cvc-code last">
                    <label>CVV Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cvc_code" value="174" size="10" class="gr-input" required />
                </li>
              <input type="submit" name="tokenex_process" value="Pay Now" class="fsSubmitButton tokenex_submit btn btn-success"/>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <div class="visa-watermark">visa</div>
        <div class="mastercard-watermark"><div></div><div></div></div>
    </section>

</body>
```

I want the 'name on card" and "card type" to be in a line..I tried placing them in the

,but its coming below it.

PLEASE FIND THE FIDDLE HERE   http://jsfiddle.net/f8Fd3/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

I added this html and class to your html

```
   <li class="card-name">
   <label>Name on card</label>
       <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
   </li>
   <li class="card-type">
       <label>Card Type</label>
       <div class="dropdown">
         <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
           <option value="1">Visa</option>
           <option value="2">Mastercard</option>
         </select>
   </div>           
   </li>
```

I added this css to your css

```
.credit-card .inputs li.card-name , .credit-card .inputs li.card-type {
   display:block;
   float:left;
    margin-bottom:30px;
 }
  .credit-card .inputs li.card-type {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

and also see this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f8Fd3/21/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `float` css property. You will need to add some `div`s to group the label and text-boxes together.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7WUC/)
**HTML:**

```
<li>
    <div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <label>Name on card</label>
            <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 80px">
            <label>Card Type</label>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
                    <option value="1">Visa</option>
                    <option value="2">Mastercard</option>
                </select>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks.So using float,you could align two div elements right?

Comment: Right. Please see I have added the html for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/Td2ug/

Simply ammend as below :

```
<label style="float:left">Name on card
            <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
</label>

<label  style="float:left">Card Type <br>
   <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">

        <option value="1">Visa</option>
        <option value="2">Mastercard</option>

      </select>
  </div>    
</label>
```

Cover the `input`s inside `label` and `float` them `left`, they will align in one line!